# Global variables in content_script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I declare the following global variable in a chrome extension "content_script":

```
var global = "global";
```

I´m able to retrieve it when executing the following code:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
  func: globalTest
});

function globalTest() {
   alert(global); // Alerts out "global"
}
```

But when I declare the following global variable in the same "content_script":

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
```

I get the *Uncaught ReferenceError: observer is not defined*
when running the following code:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
  func: observerTest
});

function observerTest() {
   observer.observe(targetNode, config); // Uncaught ReferenceError: observer is not defined
}
```

How can it be that I can access the `global` variable, but not the `observer` variable?

My goal is to add **MutationObservers** globally, so I can turn them on and off in the Chrome Extension.

**UPDATE**

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
     "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
     },
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", 
"debugger", "tabs"],
     "content_scripts": [
     {
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "js": ["jquery-3.6.0.min.js", "foreground.js"]
     }
   ],
     "web_accessible_resources": [
     {
        "resources": [ "jquery-3.6.0.min.js" ],
         "matches": [ "https://*/*" ]
     }
    ],
      "host_permissions": ["https://*/*"],
       "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
         "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
         "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
         "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
         "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
        }
      },
        "icons": {
        "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
     },
      "options_page": "options.html"
 }
```

foreground.js

```
console.log("foreground");

var global = "global";

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'characterData') {
            console.log('mutation!');
         }
    }
};

 var person = new Object();
 person.firstName = 'testFirstName';
 person.lastName = 'testLastName';
```

popup.js

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => 
 {

   chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
      func: startObserver
   });
  });
 });

function startObserver() {

    if(jQuery) {
        console.log("jQuery");
    }

    var targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('target');

     console.log(global);
     console.log(person.firstName);
     console.log(targetNode);

     var config = { characterData: true, attributes: true, 
     childList: true, subtree: true };

     observer.observe(targetNode[0], config);
  }
```

Comment: Since the situation you describe can't happen, it means there's some mistake in the code. If you can't find it, show us more code or provide a link to the entire extension. P.S. One guess so far is that `observer` is actually declared not in the content script but in an extension script.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have updated my answer with my ```popup.js```, ```manifest.json``` and ```foreground.js``` files. For testing purposes I created a global object(person) to see if I could log the ```person.firstname``` clicking the button in the popup.js

Comment: I could read the ```person.firstname``` just fine, but not the ```MutationObserver``` object. perhaps the ```MutationObserver``` needs to be injected instead of it being run in the ```content_script```. Btw, my ```background.js``` file is empty.

Comment: The problem was that the MutationObserver object was instantiated before the callback function was defined. Works like a charm now.